# Crystal Report Null Values

Tags: crystal-reports, isnull

I am new to Crystal Reports and am running into an issue.  What I'm wanting to do is show equipment name, sum of labor hours, and workorder count for a given time period.  Time period is determined by a work order close date.  The problem is I need the equipment name to show even if there were 0 workorders for the given time period.  From what I understand this can be done using 'isnull', but I'm a bit lost on the syntax and placement.  Here is my current record formula and SQL query:

```
not ({mtwodata.WO Number} startswith "P") and {mtwodata.Close Date} = {?DateRange}

 SELECT    "mtwodata"."Equipment", "mtwodata"."WO Number", "mtwodata"."Act Labor Hrs", "mtwodata"."Close Date"
 FROM      "mtwodata" "mtwodata"
 WHERE     "mtwodata"."WO Number" NOT  LIKE 'P%' AND ("mtwodata"."Close Date">='20140101' AND "mtwodata"."Close Date"<='20140131')
 ORDER BY  "mtwodata"."Equipment"
```

Comment: To clarify: do you want to select where a value in the DB is NULL? or do you want to do something with a value via formula on the report itself?  If the former, you could use the select expert, pick your field and check for null condition.  Are you sure they are null or empty strings?  Also a potential "gotcha"

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to answer your question.  I'm not looking for null values in the equipment name.  I just need the equipment name to show even if there aren't any workorders within the close date range.

Comment: Can you add the Results return by the sql to your question. That will help us see what data you have.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure, it seems like you need a LEFT JOIN to show something in table A not in table B

Comment: what is the datatype of `workorder` and how data is stored? If there are no workorders is `0` stored in that field?